# Unenabling a repeating alarm, after alarm time, just for the current day

Tags: alarm

I am running Android on a Realme 8 5G phone. I am using the standard clock app that came with my phone. Suppose I have an alarm that goes off on my Android system. But, when it rings, and the alarm screen comes up, I click on the postpone button to dismiss it, and dismiss the alarm. Later, I decide that I do not want the alarm to ring again.

Can I go into the settings and turn it off and then back on (for example, because it is a repeating alarm and I want it to ring the day after, but I do not want it to ring again, for the current day. Would this work, or is there no way to do this? Can this be done silently (without firing the alarm up again (which I think is not possible anyway))?

Thank you for your answers.